# Having trouble updating a Mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this collection setup in mongo:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f55fdede873f132ec09207e"
  },
  "edition_id": 35889464,
  "rounds": [
    {
      "round": 1,
      "image": "https://i.imgur.com/cT7aHQ9.gif",
      "type": "normal",
      "questions": [
        {
          "songs": [
            "2vfvGlqCB7oertO5VLE0sz"
          ],
          "open": false,
          "setValue": 100,
          "varValue": 50,
          "type": "normal"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

I'm trying to update a field `open`:

```
      const questionToggle = await db.collection('editions').updateOne(
        { edition_id: editionNumber },
        {
          $set: {
            [`questionToggle.$.rounds.${roundIndex}.questions.${questionIndex}.open`]: targetValue,
          },
        },
      );
      res.json(questionToggle);
```

I keep getting `MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.` any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? my variables are:

```
edition number 35889464
round 0
question 0
```

editionNumber, roundIndex, and questionIndex, respectively. I've checked and they are all of type `number`.

Comment: i can not see `questionToggle` field in your document, does provided document is element of `questionToggle` array? what is `roundIndex` and `questionIndex` it is array index that is actual in your database collection?

Comment: @turivishal the collection is called `editions`, and that is the only element in it. `roundIndex` and `questionIndex` are variables (both in this case are `0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working:

```
      const edition = await db.collection('editions').updateOne(
        { edition_id: editionNumber },
        {
          $set: {
            [`rounds.${roundIndex}.questions.${questionIndex}.open`]: targetValue,
          },
        },
      );
```

Comment: What happens if you have several items in arrays `rounds` and/or `questions`? Having only one is simple.

Comment: There are actually 3 rounds and 5 questions per round, but that's where the `roundIndex` and `questionIndex` comes in.